# Hibernate - One to many relation - foreign key always "null"

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, mapping

I have two really simple objects and one object should contain the other one in an "one-to-many" relation in a set. The objects get inserted correctly in the database, but the foreign key in the "children" table is always "null".

I can't figure out why:

This is the test-object and it hold the children in its set:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test")
public class TestObj {

    public TestObj(){}

    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private Set<Children> children = new HashSet<Children>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "testObj", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public synchronized Set<Children> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
    public synchronized void setChildren(Set<Children> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
    public void addChildren(Children child){
        children.add(child);
    }
}
```

This is the children object and it holds an back-link to the "TestObj":

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "children")
public class Children {

    public Children(){}

    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private TestObj testObj;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    public TestObj getTestObj() {
        return testObj;
    }

    public void setTestObj(TestObj testObj) {
        this.testObj = testObj;
    }
}
```

I persist this objects with this code:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = HibernateEntityMangerSingelton.getEntityManagerFactory();
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();


TestObj user = new TestObj();

Children child = new Children();
user.addChildren(child);
try {

    entityManager.persist(user);

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}finally{
    entityManager.close();
}
```

Can some explain me why this is happening?

Comment: can you post your answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's quite simple: you never initialize the `testObj` field in `Children` (which should be named Child, BTW). `Children.testObj` is the owner of the association, and is the field that is mapped to the join column, so if it's null, the join column will be null.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, thats truly simple and i tried everything :( i should go to bed!

Comment: can you please post your code? I tried the same, But still null

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem which i solved by calling setter of the owner side. The 2 metods seting and adding the children to the TestObj should be altered like this, so that the TestObj is initialized at the owner side:

```
public synchronized void setChildren(Set<Children> children) 

{



this.children = children;


for(Children child : children)
    {
    // initializing the TestObj instance in Children class (Owner side) so that it is not a null and PK can be created
            child.setTestObj(this);
    }
    }
```

The second method:

```
public void addChildren(Children child)
{
    children.add(child);
//Intializing the TestObj instance at the owner side
    child.setTestObj(this);
}
```