# JPA ManyToOne/OneToMany not inserting the value on child

Tags: java, json, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am developing a Rest API which will receive a JSON. I need to save the JSON correctly in a Postgres DB.

Right now I have:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = ALL)
    private List<Address> address;
}
```

And

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String city;
    private String number;
    private String country;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    private Customer customer;
}
```

My controller has only this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST)
public ResponseEntity create(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
    Customer customerSaved = repository.save(customer);
    return new ResponseEntity(customerSaved, CREATED);
}
```

When I send a JSON like:

```
{
   "name":"A name",
   "address":[
      {
         "country":"Brazil",
         "city":"Porto Alegre",
         "number":"000"
      }
   ]
}
```

I was expecting that the table Customer would have the name and table Address would have the three properties plus the customer_id. But the customer_id right now is null.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, you need to set the address.customer field, and not leave it null.

Comment: If you're using Jackson for the JSON conversion, you could use the `JsonManagedReference` and `JsonBackReference` annotations to automatically set the reference automatically, instead of manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the setter method of List address like below:

```
public void setAddress(Set<Address> address) {

        for (Address child : address) {
            // initializing the TestObj instance in Children class (Owner side)
            // so that it is not a null and PK can be created
            child.setCustomer(this);
        }
        this.address = address;
    }
```

[Hibernate - One to many relation - foreign key always "null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865658/hibernate-one-to-many-relation-foreign-key-always-null)

Comment: Thnnxx Man spend over 2 hours searching for the right answer